# how to change state of checkbox in listview?

Tags: android, listview

i have listview which contain checkbox and imageview. the problem is when i click listView right checkbox is not checked but checked differnt checkbox randomly and also checked mulptiple checkbox..

cell.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30dp" android:padding="2dp"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
        android:focusable="false"
        ></CheckBox>
</LinearLayout>
```

list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="saveSetting"
    android:text="Save"/> 
  <ListView android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    String[] string = { "First", "Second", "third", "Forth", "Fifth", "Sixth",
            "Seven", "Eight" };

    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        super.onCreate(b);
        setContentView(R.layout.list);
        List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String s : string) {
            arrayList.add(s);
        }
        ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        final CustomAdapter ada = new CustomAdapter(arrayList, this);
        listview.setAdapter(ada);
        // listview.setItemsCanFocus(true);
        listview.setChoiceMode(0);
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                ada.setPosition(arg2);
            }
        });
    }

    class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private List<String> items;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        int selectedPos = -1;

        public CustomAdapter(List<String> list, Context context) {
            super();
            this.items = list;
            this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return items.size();
        }

        public void setPosition(int position) {
            selectedPos = position;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public int getPosition() {
            return selectedPos;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return items.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.cBox = (CheckBox) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
                holder.iView = (ImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            holder.iView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
            holder.cBox.setText(items.get(position));
            if (selectedPos == position) {
                holder.cBox.setChecked(!holder.cBox.isChecked());

            }
            final String c=(String) holder.cBox.getText();
            holder.cBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),c , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            return convertView;

        }

        class ViewHolder {
            ImageView iView;
            CheckBox cBox;
        }

    }

    public void saveSetting(View view) {
    }

}
```

may i know what wrong with my code
thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

First you have to choose whether to add a checkbox yourself or to use CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE of ListView.

And first remove this:

```
if (selectedPos == position) {
    holder.cBox.setChecked(!holder.cBox.isChecked());
}
```

**Case 1:** If you want to use CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE:
Remove:

```
<CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30dp" android:padding="2dp"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
        android:focusable="false"
        ></CheckBox>
```

Remove:

```
listview.setChoiceMode(0);
```

You already have:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" <!-- This is for checkbox to use it as multiple choice -->
    />
```

**Case 2:** You want to put your own checkbox in the row:
Remove in ListView properties:

```
android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
```

Remove:

```
listview.setChoiceMode(0); // Useless
```

Comment: if i remove  
    if (selectedPos == position) {
        holder.cBox.setChecked(!holder.cBox.isChecked());
    }
checkbox is not checked when i click list